# Why should one use "back" in these examples?

Tags: word-usage, difference, adverbs

> **Back** at home, it was so dim.
>
> I used to play football **back** in my school days.
>
> We used to eat by hands **back** in my country.

Is **back** optional in these sentences or does it change their respective meanings in any way?

Comment: In my opinion, the last two sentences remain unchanged after removing *back*. I am not sure about the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**[Back](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/back)**" here emphasises the past. It has several meanings "**At a place previously left or mentioned**", "**In or into the past**"

- The folks **back home** are counting on him.
- He made his fortune **back in 1955**.

The sentences may be understood as:

1. **Back at home**, it was so dim. *(I left the place not long ago)*
2. I used to play football **back in my school days**. *(These are memories of the past. Probably far into the past)*
3. We used to eat by hands **back in my country**. *(I'm remembering it, the country I lived in not long ago)*

Compared to sentences without "**back**":

1. **At home**, it was so dim. *(A simple statement. It was so dim at home at some time in the past)*
2. I used to play football **in my school days**. *(When I was a school boy we used to play football - simple statement)*
3. We used to eat by hands **in my country**. *(Again, simple statement)*

Comment: Much depends on the context.